# Sparklyr Not connecting to Databricks

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, databricks, sparklyr

I am trying to connect to databricks using sparklyr or SparkR.

Now i am trying it using sparklyr.

this is how i have installed sparklyr

```
install.packages("sparklyr")

sparklyr::spark_install()  #installing spark

sprk <- spark_connect(master = "local")    # this code works perfectly and it connects to the spark, and i can work further

sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")  # this is not working 

Error i get is: Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
                Failed to start sparklyr backend: there is no package called ‘SparkR’
```

why do i need to have SparkR when i am working with sparklyr...how to solve this ,i need to connect to databricks.

Comment: Hi there! we've release some documentation on this, take a look at the link below :) 
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/sparkr/sparklyr.html#sparklyr

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the instructions of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect to install and configure databricks-connect locally. Follow the code in R/RStudio session, start a spark session using `sparkR.session()`, connect to spark using `sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")` then you can use sparklyr. However, compared with running sparklyr in a databricks notebook, some sparklyr functions are not supported when you connect to databricks from a remote location.